# Performing SQLite Queries

Tags: sqlite

I'm having problems finding examples of sqlite3 queries. The diagrams in the documentation are useless. I want to say...

```
delete from food_post where ip_address=190.17.107.106;
```

I keep getting a syntax error, though. :/

Answer (score 2):

Possibly because of multiple periods in your number. Instead try

```
delete from food_post where ip_address="190.17.107.106";
```